# Could not start process "make" qmake_all

Tags: qt

```
17:48:22: Could not start process "make" qmake_all
Error while building/deploying project Calculator (kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

My project can't run on Ubuntu
my kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.0 GCC 64bit
I am a newbie to Linux OS so how can I do

Answer (score 10):

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If you get `Cannot find -lGL` error, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why this is not selected as the best answer though?

Comment: this way worked but for arch linux the command is "sudo pacman -Sy base-devel"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens due to incorrect path in the build settings.Qt creator shows this path in red in the project settings tab.

You can either **give a correct path** as the build directory (Which then will be shown in black) or **deselect the shadow build checkbox** to resolve the error.

To access build settings click the project icon on the left pane.

this image will show how qt creator shows the incorrect path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen on Windows if you are using something like MSYS2 and its Qt/GCC builds. Finding where `make` is in MSYS2 shell (`$whereis make`) and adding to PATH does fix it. (Must restart Qt creator)